# Stick someone with something

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

Suppose you buy something like a car and after the deal, you find out that it has many mechanical problems and it didn't cost that much and the seller has conned you. please let me know that Which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you? Meanwhile, I would be thankful if you give your suggestions and say me what would you as native speaker say it this circumstance:

> - He stuck me with his lemon of a car.
> - He stuck me with the terrible deal on his lemon of a car.

[Here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-someone-with-something) I found out that the idiom "stick someone with something" means: "to force someone to have or do something less desirable", but I do not tend to talk about the satisfaction or dissatisfaction of the buyer after the contract! Instead,I'm going to talk about what he things about the type of the contract he has done.

Comment: A minor correction: we don't usually use *lemon* that way.  We would just say "a lemon" or maybe "a lemon of a car", but we wouldn't use it like an adjective like "lemon car".

Comment: @stangdon thank you very much for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 3):

We generally don't say someone gets *stuck* with a contract or deal, because they have to enter one voluntarily, and *stuck* conveys that they had no choice in the matter.

You might say...

- He really *[swindled](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swindle)* me.
- I got *[rooked](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rook)*.

These verbs have the meaning you're after; that the deal was unfair due to the seller's deception, and thus the buyer lost money.

Comment: Glad you are back! Hope I see more of your answers! :)

Comment: Thank you very much Esoteric; but wat about the verbs: "he really scammed / conned me?

Comment: And of course, can we say: he swindled / scammed / conned me with his lemon of a car?